# Konva's .draw method overlaps old draw, how do i prevent that?

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

In my code i am redrawing a rectangle every time a user moves their mouse to track it, but as said [here](https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/Shape_Redraw.html), the .draw method will not remove the old drawing of the shape.

So my question is, how do i remove the old drawing? Is there some sort of .remove() method?

Thanks in advance,

iLinked

Comment: I browsed the docs for a bit and apparently, the default behavior of a layer it to clear itself before each redraw. Can you add a [mre] to your question?

Comment: turns out the reason behind why it overlapped was because i only redrew the shape, not the layer. When i changed it it worked. Thanks!